# How to run/execute Visual FoxPro (sistem.exe file) in Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, visual-foxpro, dbf

I have a FoxPro program (program.exe) that reads/stores data in tables (some are *.dbf files and others are MySQL tables). User  access/execute the program.exe file from their  Windows 7/8/10 terminals through local network of the company. Now I need to know if its possible to put that .exe program and all its dbf tables in a linux machine hopefully everything working Ok?

Is that possible? 
I'm searching in Google and many sites and forums talks about Wine.

anybody can help me? 
excuse my english

thanks to all

Comment: Voted to close as this question has nothing to do with programming, but with running windows executables under linux or accessing it from windows on a samba share.  If people use windows to run the program you don't need wine at all, just samba.  P.S.: This belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

For the .exe file and any .dll files or binaries the program may need, it's totally OK to do so. As long as the Windows computers can access and read the shared folders, it will work. Windows clients just see a normal share and don't know that there is a Linux behind the scenes.

As for the .dbf (and I assume the related .cdx) things are a bit different. In theory it simply works, but in practice I've seen than tables when the system is under high concurrency tends to corrupt or the indexes become out of sync. This causes rare problems like missing records or searches failing.

Generally, putting a dbf based "database" in a shared folder of any kind under simultaneous use by many systems is asking for trouble (regardless of Linux or Windows hosting the shares). This of course don't applies to a proper DB server like MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It *may* be possible.

**Wine** is you best bet.

Wine acts like an MS Windows emulator so the you may run programs built for Windows under it host OS. Wine has gotten better over the years, but it's definitely not a sure bet. You can also have a look at Crossover Office, which is a non-free program built around Wine. The extra, non-free *stuff* the developers add around Wine, making it into Crossover, is intended to make running a Windows program in Linux *just work* which, occasionally, does happen.

Comment: Read the question again; he doesn't want to run the file on linux, he wants it to reside on linux and have windows7/8/10 machines access it.  Your response won't help him at all.